# this/it is the case

Tags: it-this

I got a professional language correction of a paper. The corrector changed several

```
it is (not) the case
```

to

```
this is (not) the case.
```

As an example,

```
Let us assume that A is invertible (although in practice it->this is often not the case).
```

I guess I do not understand the difference. Does negation play a role here? Could someone help me understand the distinction?

Some of my

```
"A" might also be used, as it is the case in e.g. "citation"
```

were changed by removing "it". Does it means that "this" is implied here?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Examples would help here. It's always easier to build an answer if there is a foundation to base it on. You can [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/524776/edit) to add them.

Comment: What do you mean "and the other way round"? That some instances of "this" were changed to "it"? Additional context for your examples would help a lot here, please [edit] to show the whole sentence and the one before it.

Comment: @nnnnnn No, I was wrong. Carefully, looking at the correction I can see no such instance.

Comment: << Let us assume that A is invertible (although in practice it is often not the case). >> is not used; 'it' would have to refer back to the covert 'this situation', a leap too far. However << Let us assume that A is invertible (although in practice this is often not the case). >> is commonly used. 'This' as a deleted form of 'this state/situation' is probably considered an acceptable shortening.